# How to check web page load time in Jmeter without using api.? Is it possible to perform load testing in jmeter without using api's?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, web-api-testing

I was given with a task in which I need to check load time of webpages in Jmeter and there is not any api's available. so hot to perform load testing without having api's.

Comment: have you tried ${__time(dd/MM/yyyy,)}? https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and configure it to hit the page which you need to measure

   [image]
2. At the "Advanced" tab tick `Retrieve All Embedded Resources` and `Parallel Downloads` boxes, in addition you can exclude external domains there as well to limit JMeter to only your application:

   [image]

   More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/)
3. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan (real browsers download embedded resources like images, scripts, styles, fonts, but do this only once)
4. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to your Test Plan and configure it to send [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) which browsers normally send like [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept), etc.
5. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to handle [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

That's it, now you should have more or less realistic page load time. Remember that JMeter is not a browser so it doesn't execute JavaScript so if there are any JavaScript-generated calls - you will need to add a separate HTTP Request sampler per call and put them all under [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)